# "Couldn't load plugin" - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-plugin

I am trying to watch a video on Google Chrome and I got this error below.
Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
I can view videos normally on Youtube but with this page I have the problem.
Thank you.

[image: [Error screenshot: black screen with "Couldn't load plugin" text centered, on a gray background]

Comment: What device are you attempting to view the video on? The device may not support the plugin.

Comment: What plugin is it trying to load?

Comment: Thank you. I am browsing it on laptop. For the plugin I don't know what it is. How can I check that?

Comment: Try going to [here](https://www.adobe.com/swf/software/flash/about/flashAbout_info_small.swf) and seeing what it says.

Comment: Hi, the exact same problem happened with the link you gave.

Comment: So then it is flash that is not working. Try my answer.

Comment: Also, tell whoever manages the site that the link is accessible from anywhere without authentication.

Comment: Try starting Windows in Safe Mode w/ Networking and try the web site.

Answer (score 2):

In versions of Chrome prior to version 57, it was possible to configure Flash via `chrome://plugins` however this feature has since been removed.  For the newest versions of Chrome, if the browser displays the error `"Couldn't load plugins"` then try the following remedies:

1. Ensure that Chrome is configured to allow the desired website to run Flash. Unfortunately, Chrome will no longer allow a website to Flash to run by default, or even popup a small dialog to ask permission.   Instead, it is necessary to *explicitly* configure Chrome.  To do this, navigate to `chrome://settings/content` and then either enable Flash for all sites by choosing `"Allow sites to run Flash"` (which, depending upon how the browser is used, may be a security hazard) or else enable it for *only* the desired website via `"Manage Exceptions..."` and then enter the desired site, e.g. **mysite.com**, and press enter.
2. If that doesn't work, uninstall Chrome and reinstall.  This is tricky because the uninstaller program does not fully uninstall Chrome.   Find instructions on the Internet to help with this (it involves deleting directories, modifying the registry, etc.)   Also note that, although this step is frequently recommended, in my experience it is a long-shot because it seldom works.
3. If that doesn't work, then [download](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and install the Pepper Flash Player from Adobe.  However, this approach can lead to another issue, which is that **Chrome will not run an external Flash Player if its own bundled Flash Player is of a newer version.**   Since Chrome auto updates itself frequently, and since Adobe releases new Flash Player versions frequently, this may happen before long.   To work-around this issue, run Chrome with the `--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash` command-line switch.

PS, Whatever you do, if you download and install Flash Player then do so *only* from **adobe.com** domains.   Do not, under any circumstances, respond to popups advertisements from other domains which offer to "fix" or install Flash Player as these may introduce serious security hazards.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the plugin that is not working is flash.

1. Go to `chrome://plugins`
2. Click `Details`
3. Find `Adobe Flash Player`
4. Under `Type: PPAPI` click `Enable`

If that doesn't work, [update Chrome.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
[Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you. I tried both but it still doens't work.

Comment: Could you help me check the link if it works for you?
https://echoess.uml.edu:8443/ess/echo/presentation/54e77c41-9a55-4baa-b1f2-68af0415dd42?ec=true

Comment: @NguyenVanHuan Try IE or Firefox then. It really should work. It works for me in FF and Edge.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both of them as well. However, I got the following errors.
IE: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
FF: The connection was interrupted
 The connection to echoess.uml.edu:8443 was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: Are you using anything that would prevent plugins (VPN, overzealous web filter, etc.)?

Comment: I don't intend to install any of these. However, if possible, could you help me check that?

Comment: I can't check that because I don't have your software installed. Could you try an online proxy such as [hide.me](https://hide.me/en/proxy)?

Comment: Thank you. I have just checked it but I still can not access the site. May this problem relate to region?

Comment: Perhaps. I doubt it though. Try it on another computer and see if it works. I can't really help anymore though.

Comment: I tried it with my friend laptop and the same problem happened. It is really irritating.

Comment: This is most likely a network problem or filter. To confirm this you could try a free VPN and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now. I will let you know if it works or not.

Comment: You said you were using Chrome. Chrome has Flash Player built-in. It worked for me and saw the code that asked for Flash: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="echo_desktop.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="echo-desktop" title="Adobe Flash Player" style="visibility: visible;">`

Comment: @Sun It works for me too but not for them. FF and IE didn't work and another computer didn't work either so it's probably a network filter of some sort.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. My account had some problems. I reinstalled Google Chrome and it works perfect now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @user3126592 No problem. If you think I helped please upvote my post.